# Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found long, expecting union in hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

Need help!!!

I am streaming twitter feeds into hdfs using `flume` and loading it up in `hive` for analysis.

The steps are as follows:

Data in [hdfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAUA5.png):

I have described the `avro schema` in an `avsc` file and put it in hadoop:

```
 {"type":"record",
 "name":"Doc",
 "doc":"adoc",
 "fields":[{"name":"id","type":"string"},
       {"name":"user_friends_count","type":["int","null"]},
       {"name":"user_location","type":["string","null"]},
       {"name":"user_description","type":["string","null"]},
       {"name":"user_statuses_count","type":["int","null"]},
       {"name":"user_followers_count","type":["int","null"]},
       {"name":"user_name","type":["string","null"]},
       {"name":"user_screen_name","type":["string","null"]},
       {"name":"created_at","type":["string","null"]},
       {"name":"text","type":["string","null"]},
       {"name":"retweet_count","type":["boolean","null"]},
       {"name":"retweeted","type":["boolean","null"]},
       {"name":"in_reply_to_user_id","type":["long","null"]},
       {"name":"source","type":["string","null"]},
       {"name":"in_reply_to_status_id","type":["long","null"]},
       {"name":"media_url_https","type":["string","null"]},
       {"name":"expanded_url","type":["string","null"]}]}
```

I have written an .hql file to create a table and loaded data in it:

```
 create table tweetsavro
    row format serde
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
    stored as inputformat
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
    outputformat
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
    tblproperties ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///avro_schema/AvroSchemaFile.avsc');

    load data inpath '/test/twitter_data/FlumeData.*' overwrite into table tweetsavro;
```

I have successfully run the .hql file but when i run the `select *from <tablename>` command in hive it shows the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0aPw.png)

The output of tweetsavro is:

```
hive> desc tweetsavro;
OK
id                      string                                      
user_friends_count      int                                         
user_location           string                                      
user_description        string                                      
user_statuses_count     int                                         
user_followers_count    int                                         
user_name               string                                      
user_screen_name        string                                      
created_at              string                                      
text                    string                                      
retweet_count           boolean                                     
retweeted               boolean                                     
in_reply_to_user_id     bigint                                      
source                  string                                      
in_reply_to_status_id   bigint                                      
media_url_https         string                                      
expanded_url            string                                      
Time taken: 0.697 seconds, Fetched: 17 row(s)
```

Comment: Instead of attaching a picture, please format your code/error in accordance with the specific [`Markdown`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: What's the output of `describe tweetsavro`?

Comment: I do not see long in the table or avro schema but the error is regarding long data?

Comment: You don't see long in the tweetsavro description because there is no long type in hive. The long type is converted to bigint in hive. For more info refer the following: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe

Comment: Generic and simpler version of this answer at [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865899/hive-query-execution-failed-with-exception-java-io-ioexceptionorg-apache-avro/63251942#63251942)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the exact same issue. The issue existed in the timestamp field("created_at" column in your case) which i was trying to insert as string into my new table. My assumption was this data would be in `[ "null","string"]` format in my source. I analyzed the source avro schema which got generated from the sqoop import --as-avrodatafile process. The avro schema generated from import had the below signature for the timestamp column.
`{
    "name" : "order_date",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "order_date",
    "sqlType" : "93"
  },`

SqlType 93 stands for Timestamp datatype. So in my target table Avro Schema file I changed the data type to 'long' and this solved the issue. My guess is possibly the mismatch of datatype in one of your columns.