# Hive query execution: Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found double, expecting union

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hive

I am trying to execute a simple

```
select * from table limit 1;
```

Statement in hive on an external table. But facing failue with execption:

```
java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found double, expecting union.
```

Can Someone help me understand what this means? I have checked the schema file and the "default":null is already given.

What is the exact reason for this exception occuring?

I tried understanding [an already existing discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480155/failed-with-exception-java-io-ioexceptionorg-apache-avro-avrotypeexception-fou).

The schema looks something like this:

```
{"type":"record",
 "name":"VISIBILITY",
 "namespace":"pentaho_etl",
 "fields":[ {"name":"ID",               "type":["null","long"],     "default":null},
            {"name":"VERSION_ID",       "type":["null","long"],     "default":null},
            {"name":"IMP_CLASS",        "type":["null","string"],   "default":null},
            {"name":"NAME",             "type":["null","string"],   "default":null},
            {"name":"DL_SCHEMA_VERSN",  "type":["null","long"],     "default":null},
            {"name":"DL_FEED_TM",       "type":["null","string"],   "default":null},
            {"name":"DL_WFID",          "type":["null","long"],     "default":null},
            {"name":"DL_ENT_NM",        "type":["null","string"],   "default":null},
            {"name":"DL_JID",           "type":["null","long"],     "default":null},
            {"name":"DL_DATASET_ID",    "type":["null","long"],     "default":null},
            {"name":"DL_FD_DT",         "type":["null","string"],   "default":null}
        ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide avro schema ?

Comment: there are couple of mistakes in your schema file, are you sure you used same file? (First element of fields array - it should be "null" instead of "null , 7th element of fields array - it should be "DL_WFID" instead of DL_WFID")

Comment: Does "describe table" shows schema same as defined by avro schema file?

Comment: @Shubhangi, I made the edit required. It was a manual error while I wrote the schema here. And yes, the describe table is showing me the correct columns and datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

I know, it is old question, but it is unanswered, hence, adding little information that I know about this issue, so that, it helps others.

This is very common issue, we face due to mismatch between the table schema and schema contained in the avro file.

Though, avro file is binary, you can open it in any text editor and get its schema from initial few lines. This schema is not matching with the schema of the table, which you can get using `show create table table_name`.
Then you can compare these 2 schemas column by column to find any discrepancies e.g. your avro is showing a column as double but your schema might have it as string.